# Rails 500 error redirecting to blank page with RIA.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, nginx, passenger

I'm using **passenger** with **nginx**. I have a custom .ria format included. If a route ends with .ria the page uses javascript and ajax to enhance the user experience. If the .ria is not present it falls back to not using javascript. So, when I get an error, the fall-back displays the custom error pages just fine, but with the .ria it shows a blank page.

Any idea on what could be happening or what is missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

The problem was with the Excpetion Notification plugin. The plugin renders the 500.html page for type.html formats and for type.all it renders nothing.

```
respond_to do |type|
  type.html { render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/500.html", :status => "500 Error" }
  type.all  { render :nothing => true, :status => "500 Error" }
end
```

So I overrode the method in the ApplicationController with the following

```
respond_to do |type|
  type.html { render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/500.html", :status => "500 Error" }
  type.ria { render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/500.html", :status => "500 Error" }
  type.all  { render :nothing => true, :status => "500 Error" }
end
```

And now everything works just fine :)